# How to find the right path of integration to get the asymptotic partition formula

Tags: cv.complex-variables, asymptotics, partitions, ramanujan, circle-method

I am trying to understand how the asymptotic partition formula $p(n) \sim \frac{e^{\pi\sqrt{\frac{2n}{3}}}}{4n\sqrt3} $ was derived for a project and have been reading and following many papers.

I am able to get to this integral:

$$p(n) = \int_U f_n(\alpha)e(-n\alpha) \,d\alpha$$

where $f_N(\alpha) := \sum_{k=1}^N p(k)e(k\alpha) = \prod_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{1-e(k\alpha)}$ is the truncated generating function for $p(n)$, $e(x) = e^{2\pi ix}$ and $U$ is any interval of length 1, but am unsure as to how to get to the next step from here.

In many papers, the next step is using Farey series and Ford Circles to define the integration path as shown below:

[Image of the integration path using Farey series and Ford Circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rwHS.png)

I am however confused as to how they get to that from my current integral and whether evaluating it will even give me the asymptotic formula I am after.

I love this problem and enjoy working on it as I learn more and more about this massively interesting problem. If someone could help me out, it would be hugely appreciated :)

Thank you!

PS: it's my first time posting here so apologies if my formatting is not great

Comment: Welcome to mathoverflow! Your formatting looks pretty good to me - and that's really helpful.

Comment: As a warmup you can see an easier argument that gives this asymptotic up to a factor of $O(n)$ and then a sketch of a somewhat harder (but not the full) argument that gives this asymptotic up to a factor of $O(1)$ here, using the saddle point method: https://qchu.wordpress.com/2016/05/20/the-man-who-knew-partition-asymptotics/